# Tensorflow: How to retrieve information from the prediction Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have found a neural network for semantic segmentation purpose. The network works just fine, I feed my training, validation and test data and I get the output (segmented parts in different colors). Until here, all is OK. I am using Keras with Tensorflow 1.7.0, GPU enabled. Python version is 3.5

What I want to achieve though is to get access to the pixel groups (segments) so that I can get their boundaries' image coordinates, i.e. an array of points which forms the boundary of the segment X shown in green in the prediction image.

How to do that? Obviously I cannot put the entire code here but here is a snippet which I should modify to achieve what I would like to:

I have the following in my **evaluate function**:

```
    def evaluate(model_file):
    net = load_model(model_file, custom_objects={'iou_metric': create_iou_metric(1 + len(PART_NAMES)),
                                                 'acc_metric': create_accuracy_metric(1 + len(PART_NAMES), output_mode='pixelwise_mean')})

    img_size = net.input_shape[1]
    image_filename = lambda fp: fp + '.jpg'
    d_test_x = TensorResize((img_size, img_size))(ImageSource(TEST_DATA, image_filename=image_filename))
    d_test_x = PixelwiseSubstract([103.93, 116.78, 123.68], use_lane_names=['X'])(d_test_x)
    d_test_pred = Predict(net)(d_test_x)
    d_test_pred.metadata['properties'] = ['background'] + PART_NAMES

    d_x, d_y = process_data(VALIDATION_DATA, img_size)
    d_x = PixelwiseSubstract([103.93, 116.78, 123.68], use_lane_names=['X'])(d_x)
    d_y = AddBackgroundMap(use_lane_names=['Y'])(d_y)

    d_train = Join()([d_x, d_y])
    print('losses:', net.evaluate_generator(d_train.batch_array_tuple_generator(batch_size=3), 3))

    # the tensor which needs to be modified
    pred_y = Predict(net)(d_x)
    Visualize(('slices', 'labels'))(Join()([d_test_x, d_test_pred]))
    Visualize(('slices', 'labels', 'labels'))(Join()([d_x, pred_y, d_y]))
```

As for the Predict function, here is the snippet:

Alternatively, I've found that by using the following, one can get access to the tensor:

```
#    for sample_img, in d_x.batch_array_tuple_generator(batch_size=3, n_samples=5):
#        aa = net.predict(sample_img)
#        indexes = np.argmax(aa,axis=3)
#        print(indexes)
#        import pdb
#        pdb.set_trace()
```

But I have no idea how this works, I've never used pdb, therefore no idea.

In case if anyone wants to also see the **training function**, here it is:

```
def train(model_name='refine_res', k=3, recompute=False, img_size=224,
        epochs=10, train_decoder_only=False, augmentation_boost=2, learning_rate=0.001,
        opt='rmsprop'):

    print("Traning on: " + str(PART_NAMES))
    print("In Total: " + str(1 + len(PART_NAMES)) + " parts.")

    metrics = [create_iou_metric(1 + len(PART_NAMES)),
               create_accuracy_metric(1 + len(PART_NAMES), output_mode='pixelwise_mean')]

    if model_name == 'dummy':
        net = build_dummy((224, 224, 3), 1 + len(PART_NAMES))  # 1+ because background class
    elif model_name == 'refine_res':
        net = build_resnet50_upconv_refine((img_size, img_size, 3), 1 + len(PART_NAMES), k=k, optimizer=opt, learning_rate=learning_rate, softmax_top=True,
                                           objective_function=categorical_crossentropy,
                                           metrics=metrics, train_full=not train_decoder_only)
    elif model_name == 'vgg_upconv':
        net = build_vgg_upconv((img_size, img_size, 3), 1 + len(PART_NAMES), k=k, optimizer=opt, learning_rate=learning_rate, softmax_top=True,
                               objective_function=categorical_crossentropy,metrics=metrics, train_full=not train_decoder_only)
    else:
        net = load_model(model_name)

    d_x, d_y = process_data(TRAINING_DATA, img_size, recompute=recompute, ignore_cache=False)
    d = Join()([d_x, d_y])

    # create more samples by rotating top view images and translating
    images_to_be_rotated = {}
    factor = 5
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(TRAINING_DATA, topdown=False):
        for name in dirs:
            format = str(name + '/' + name)  # construct the format of foldername/foldername
            images_to_be_rotated.update({format: factor})

    d_aug = ImageAugmentation(factor_per_filepath_prefix=images_to_be_rotated, rotation_variance=90, recalc_base_seed=True)(d)
    d_aug = ImageAugmentation(factor=3 * augmentation_boost, color_interval=0.03, shift_interval=0.1, contrast=0.4,  recalc_base_seed=True, use_lane_names=['X'])(d_aug)
    d_aug = ImageAugmentation(factor=2, rotation_variance=20, recalc_base_seed=True)(d_aug)
    d_aug = ImageAugmentation(factor=7 * augmentation_boost, rotation_variance=10, translation=35, mirror=True, recalc_base_seed=True)(d_aug)

    # apply augmentation on the images of the training dataset only

    d_aug = AddBackgroundMap(use_lane_names=['Y'])(d_aug)
    d_aug.metadata['properties'] = ['background'] + PART_NAMES

    # substract mean and shuffle
    d_aug = Shuffle()(d_aug)
    d_aug, d_val = RandomSplit(0.8)(d_aug)
    d_aug = PixelwiseSubstract([103.93, 116.78, 123.68], use_lane_names=['X'])(d_aug)
    d_val = PixelwiseSubstract([103.93, 116.78, 123.68], use_lane_names=['X'])(d_val)

    # Visualize()(d_aug)

    d_aug.configure()
    d_val.configure()
    print('training size:', d_aug.size())
    batch_size = 4

    callbacks = []
    #callbacks += [EarlyStopping(patience=10)]
    callbacks += [ModelCheckpoint(filepath="trained_models/"+model_name + '.hdf5', monitor='val_iou_metric', mode='max',
                                  verbose=1, save_best_only=True)]
    callbacks += [CSVLogger('logs/'+model_name + '.csv')]
    history = History()
    callbacks += [history]

    # sess = K.get_session()
    # sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())

    net.fit_generator(d_aug.batch_array_tuple_generator(batch_size=batch_size, shuffle_samples=True), steps_per_epoch=d_aug.size() // batch_size,
                      validation_data=d_val.batch_array_tuple_generator(batch_size=batch_size), validation_steps=d_val.size() // batch_size,
                      callbacks=callbacks, epochs=epochs)

    return {k: (max(history.history[k]), min(history.history[k])) for k in history.history.keys()}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for segmentation tasks, considering that your batch is one image, each pixel in the image is assigned a probability to belong to a class. Suppose you have 5 classes, and the image has 784 pixels(28x28) , you will get from the `net.predict` an array of shape `(784,5)` each pixel among 784 is assigned 5 probabilities values to belong to those classes. when you do `np.argmax(aa,axis=3)` you get the index of the highests probabilities for each pixel that would of shape `(784,1)` you can then reshape it to 28x28 `indexes.reshape(28,28)` and you get the mask of your predictions.

Reducing the problem to a 7x7 dimension and 4 classes(0-3) that looks like

```
array([[2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1],
   [3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
   [3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1],
   [1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0],
   [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
   [0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3]])
```

you want to extract the indexes where the model predicted 1

```
segment_1=np.where(indexes==1)
```

since its 2 dimension array, segment_1 will be 2x7 array,where the first array is the row indexes, and second array will be column value.

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]), array([1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 0, 1, 4, 6, 5, 0, 4, 2, 3, 5]))
```

looking at first number in the first and second array,`0 and 1` point to where the located in `indexes`

You can extract its value like

```
indexes[segment_1]
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

and then proceed with second class you want to get ,lets say 2

```
segment_2=np.where(image==2)
segment_2
(array([0, 0, 2, 2, 5, 5, 6]), array([0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1]))
```

and if you want to get each classes itsself.
you can create a copy of `indexes` for each class,4 copies in total `class_1=indexes` and set to zero any value that is not equal to 1. `class_1[class_1!=1]=0` and get something like this

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

for the eye, you may think that there are countour but from this example, you can tell that there is no clear contour of each segment. The only way i could think of,is to loop the image in rows and record where the value change and do the same in columns.
I am not entired sure if this would be ideal situation.
I hope i covered some part of your question.
 PDB is just a debugging package that allows you execute your code step by step

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is all quite complicated to be honest. I guess I'll simply conduct contour detection or color segmentation on the resulting image coming from the network, using a vision library. This way I won't have to deal with matrices, indexes and all that. Nevertheless, I'll accept your answer as this is the most relevant solution in this context.

Comment: i understand, this link illustrates how to extract and color the image from prediction of multiclass, just in case you would be interested https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/blob/master/Scripts/test_segmentation_camvid.py

Comment: Oh that's great actually, it's exactly what I was having in mind. Thanks!